# backup exec - backup to disk offline

Tags: backup

We are running backup exec 9.1 doing a backup to disk to portable hard disk drives.

When we run the backup manually it works fine.

But when the backup is setup to run in the evening on a schedule it does not run as the backup to disk folders goes offline and therefore has to be switched back on line. After we have done this the backup runs and completes fine.

Any ideas?

We have tried leaving the progam open and this makes no difference.

Server is Windows 2003 SBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about in the "Pre-Command" section.. add a small script that simply reads or writes to a file from that drive.. effectively initializing it.. (haven't tested, but theoretically it should work)

maybe something like this: (assuming removable drive is mapped to J:)

```
echo 'This forces the drive to be active for BEX' > J:\i.txt
```

If necessary, I'm sure you can figure out the Post command to remove the file again..

Comment: @Adam Chetnik: Did this work? (From what I think I understood, "Offline" is a purely internal state of the "Backup To Disk" database structure within Backup Exec. Whether a Windows script can write to the same parent folder should not be able to change this.)

Answer (score 0):

Waht make of external drive?  We have had some WD units that go to sleep and then are unavailable to BU Exec.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround with script

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this.

In newer versions of Backup Exec this is scriptable.

In one of their KB articles Veritas have suggestions for three workarounds. The third is the one that uses the "BEMCLI" PowerShell scripting interface.

> Then you can mark the storage online with one of the following methods:
>
> 1. Set the folder to Online manually in the storage tab of the User Interface.
> 2. Restart Backup Exec services.
> 3. Use the following BEMCLI command in a batch file(see attachment) to mark all disk storage back online.(this can be
>      executed with windows task scheduler a few minutes after the storage goes offline.)
>
>    ```
>    CD\
>    powershell.exe -command "&{import-module bemcli;Get-BEDiskStorageDevice | Set-BEDiskStorageDevice -Disabled $false}"
>    ```

- Source: Veritas KB: TECH189831: [*Backup to Disk Storage (B2D) folders in Backup Exec 2012 go offline when Backup Exec Database Maintenance occurs.*](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH189831) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/07UQy#selection-1743.0-1757.119).)

### There are two types of Backup To Disk

Backup exec distinguishes between `B2D` (Backup-To-Disk) and `RB2D` (Removable Backup-To-Disk).

In the script above they use the `Get-BEDiskStorageDevice` command. This is for B2D. E.g. a NAS.

For RB2D, e.g. a Tandberg RDX USB cartridge drive, the script needs to use `Get-BEDiskCartridgeDevice` and `Set-BEDiskCartridgeDevice`

- Source: Veritas KB: TECH189831: [*What is the difference between a B2D (Backup-To-Disk) and RB2D (Removable Backup-To-Disk) folder?*](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.000028963), (Archived [here](https://archive.is/g2NCd).)